# Login as user "Administrator" vs. ".\Administrator"

Tags: remote-desktop, domain, authentication

I'm using Remote Desktop to log in to a remote machine.

What is the difference between specifying `.\` before the username, and not?

For example:

```
Username = Administrator
```

and

```
Username = .\Administrator
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In example A you would be referring to the Domain Administrator (if you had one).

In example B you would be referring to the local Administrator account on the specific PC.